# Is it bad practice to use the weak attribute to write test code in c?

Tags: c, testing, attributes, weak

Is it good practice to use the weak attribute in production code so that for test code one can override functions?

Comment: I suggest you check the Stack Exchange Q&A site on [Software Quality Assurance and Testing](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/), maybe you will find it helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it is *good practice*, but there are ways to override functions in test code that do not interfere with production code:

- using macros that redefine the function names you wish to override
- using `LD_PRELOAD`
- using macros that expand to `__weak` in debug mode and to nothing in production mode.